# How to fit all columns in one page while print in excel Using VB.Net or C#

Tags: c#, .net, excel, vb.net

I am developping a desktop application with Vb.Net and i want to export some reports in Excel Format.
Now everting works well but when i open an excel file exported with my app, I press ctrl+p, then all columns are not fitting in print tab. I want to fit them in one page.
Thanks for Any Help.

.                           .

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.